run vue playwright e2e tests in GitHub actions
While trying to write my CI using GitHub actions,
This is one step that I'm not able to do, run the e2e tests.

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 20

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
        working-directory: front-end

      - name: Install playwright browsers
        run: npx playwright install --with-deps
        working-directory: front-end

      - name: Run tests
        # timeout-minutes: 10
        run: npm run test:e2e
        working-directory: front-end

I have tried so many combinations, but none of them worked.
please help :)

what are the errors...?
